# Is waiting needed after TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), exit_code)?

Tags: windows, win32-process

The documentation for TerminateProcess says, in part:

```
This function stops execution of all threads within the process and requests
cancellation of all pending I/O.

...

TerminateProcess is asynchronous; it initiates termination and returns
immediately. If you need to be sure the process has terminated, call the
WaitForSingleObject function with a handle to the process.
```

This leaves some ambiguity about what happens if you use TerminateProcess to commit process suicide, like this:

```
TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), exit_code)
```

Logically that should be sufficient, but the documentation *says* that execution may continue afterwards, which is dangerous if you are calling TerminateProcess due to a bug that leaves your process in an indeterminate state.

The closest thing I have found to confirmation that waiting-on-suicide is not needed is the source code to _invoke_watson in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\misc\invalid_parameter.cpp
```

The last thing this function does is to call TerminateProcess on itself - with no wait.

It would be good to get certainty and I wanted to ask this here so that the answer can serve as a supplement to the documentation.

Comment: I don't know, but no matter how corrupt your process is, it should be safe to call `TerminateProcess` followed by `Sleep(INFINITE);` just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I dislike doing things "just to be on the safe side". That leads to ugliness like allocating "a few" extra elements in an array, just to be safe. I'd rather use documented guarantees.

But, you are correct that there is no real harm in putting on a belt as well as suspenders.

Comment: I have a suspicion that TerminateProcess *is* synchronous in this one case (in fact I seem to recall reading that that's what ExitProcess actually does!) but unless someone can find documentation that says so it is probably best to stick to the documented contract. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I got this answer from somebody offline who preferred not to post it here themselves:

My take on the user-mode documentation is that TerminateProcess is in general something that one process does to another and the documentation is written for this generality, and in this sense is correct and reasonable.

Give TerminateProcess a handle to some other process and you of course want that the call comes back to you for your continued operation.

What the documentation makes a point of is that the call's success does not mean that the other process has terminated, just that its termination has been successfully got under way.

If you rely on more than this, then you're surely doing something wrong. Investigating what exactly is reliable, or even thinking about it, has therefore never seemed very useful to me. As much as I've bothered, I've taken it all to mean that by the time TerminateProcess returns to you the other process and all its threads are already marked as terminated - literally, they have the Terminated bit set in the ETHREAD - but continues executing APCs, typically for such things as completing or cancelling I/O. Though this continued execution is greatly constrained, it may take some indefinite time. So, if you need to know that all execution is done, you watch for the process to get signalled.

Of course, to call TerminateProcess to terminate another process is a brutal thing to do, which the documentation also makes a point of saying.

## Same Process

Calling TerminateProcess to terminate your own process is no less brutal. With one exception, it's very much a last resort, and even in that context, a really desperate one. Anyone who does it must have many bigger problems than what the call might return to, else surely they would call ExitProcess which explicitly does not return (but might leave the process in a deadlock).

Self-terminating via TerminateProcess introduces the case that one of the threads that's being terminated is the current thread. The post-termination APC processing is not activated for it: in the Windows 7 kernel, see PspTerminateThreadByPointer, which again makes the special case that user-mode termination of the current thread goes to the non-returning PspExitThread instead of queueing an APC for the final exit.

So, my reading is that TerminateProcess with -1 as the handle does not return, but that if you were in the kernel for the very last instructions that execute for the calling thread, you could see that other threads in your process may still execute to process APCs but yours has its APC queue drained and is about to be switched away from, never to come back. Indeed, if at this time your thread somehow has an APC to process, the kernel bug-checks!

By the way, the exception to TerminateProcess being brutal is that it's essentially the last thing that NTDLL does even for the relatively gentle self-termination via ExitProcess. It surely is well-known, yet it always surprises me, that to handle RtlExitUserProcess, NTDLL calls NtTerminateProcess *twice*. First, there's user-mode cleanup and a call to NtTerminateProcess giving NULL as the handle. If this succeeds, there's more user-mode cleanup, ending with a call to NtTerminateProcess giving -1 as the handle.

Well, that last call is just what you get from TerminateProcess with -1 as the handle. When you self-terminate via TerminateProcess you're just skipping past the clean-up, in both user mode and kernel mode, that you'd have got from ExitProcess. Anyway, when the TerminateProcess is, in effect, done by NTDLL as the end of ExitProcess, it's plainly expected not to return.

Comment: I have had Microsoft people recommend using TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), exit_code) to kill chrome child processes in order to avoid the CPU/disk cost of a clean shutdown by the process itself. These "clean" shutdowns can be particularly expensive if data is paged out.

That is, brutal as it is, committing suicide with TerminateProcess does appear to be a recommend practice.

Comment: We continue to hit problems in Chrome with TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), exit_code); returning, but only on machines with certain third-party software in our process. The tracking bug is crbug.com/820518